# Can't run x-executable through gui/shell

Tags: compiling

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and today I was trying to get `g++` to work.

I compiled:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

and then I compiled it with `g++ main.cpp -o main` and it compiled correctly. The problem is when trying to run it from the shell (GUI), it just won't run. Running it from the Terminal works (with `./main`).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written a terminal program, not a GUI program, there's no graphical interface loaded at all by your program.  So it "not running" from the GUI doesn't mean it isn't actually running.

If you run it form the GUI, you need to run it as "Run from Terminal".  Otherwise it won't show any output ever.

However, you should probably instead be running from the terminal, navigating to the directory you saved the output in (the `main` file), then run it as you did.

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm just used to Windows! How do I "Run from Terminal"?

Comment: You did it already, opened the terminal and did `./main`.  However... lemme add to my answer

Comment: Oh! Right, tl;dr GUI can run from GUI and Output will only show if run from terminal ( using std::cout ).

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is one more - If I do chmod -x main I get an error popup asking me to search for a program that can run it. There is yes and no.

If I press no it just cancels and if I press yes it just searches for a while then hangs.

Also after doing this I can't run it from Terminal it gives me "Permission Denied"

Comment: Then don't bother with the chmod +x, just build it like you did and run from terminal.

Comment: Alright! Tanks I'll mark as helpful of course!